# use postfix with ssl certificate that has a password

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, postfix, tls, sasl

i have gone through a couple of tutorials on how to set up postfix on ubuntu with support for my ssl certificate:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix
- http://www.projektfarm.com/en/support/howto/postfix_smtp_auth_tls.html

but neither of them mention what i am trying to do, so maybe i'm missing something.

my certificate file requires a password (at least it does when i start apache using this same certificate), however, at no stage do i enter this certificate's password when starting up or configuring postfix.

how would i start up or configure postfix with the password required to load the certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the postfix configuration file is located in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. the lines within this file which deal with tls are:

```
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/mydomain.com.root.ca.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.com.key.unencrypted
```

none of these files require a password. note that the unencrypted key file may be generated from an encrypted key file (ie a key file that does have a password) using the command:

```
openssl rsa -in /etc/ssl/mydomain.com.key.encrypted -out /etc/ssl/mydomain.com.key.unencrypted
```

from everything i have read, i don't think it is possible to pass the encrypted key file straight to postfix - i think it has to be an unencrypted key file that is passed in.

Comment: This worked for Red Hat 7 as well